# container mount success, but directorys are not the same

Tags: docker, containers

I create a container with the following command. Docker inspect shows the mounts are success.

But actually the contents in the directories in host and container are not the same.

I have tried to mount /l3/mysql/conf2 to /etc/mysql, but it doesn't work too.

environment:

Lubuntu 22.04

Docker version 20.10.15, build fd82621

docker image: mysql:5.7

```sh
docker pull mysql:5.7

docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --privileged=true
-v /l3/mysql/log:/var/log/mysql
-v /l3/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
-v /l3/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
--name=mysql
mysql:5.7

# directories are created in host, but all of them are empty

cd /l3/mysql/conf

ls

# but the Mounts are created

docker inspect my mysql
```

```sh
<<'END'
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/l3/mysql/conf",
                "Destination": "/ect/mysql/conf.d",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/l3/mysql/data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/l3/mysql/log",
                "Destination": "/var/log/mysql",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
END
```

```sh
# in the container, there are three config files

root@380a7767bae4:/etc/mysql/conf.d# ls
docker.cnf  mysql.cnf  mysqldump.cnf
```

When I create a new file test.txt in the host /l3/mysql/conf/, there is no test.txt in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d

```sh
root@lezhang-Lubuntu:/l3/mysql/conf# ls
test.txt

root@380a7767bae4:/etc/mysql/conf.d# ls
docker.cnf  mysql.cnf  mysqldump.cnf
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the two PNG files you attached files that are in the directory?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] with enough application source code to demonstrate the issue (in readable and runnable text form, not images)?

Comment: @DavidMaze Tanks for your advice. Ich reformed my questen.

Comment: What you describe sounds normal: Docker creates new empty directories as the host mount points, and then the contents of the host directory hide the files that were originally in the container.  Bind mounts never republish image content to the host, they always hide image content with host content.

Comment: It seems not normal.
When I create a file test.txt in host, it does not appear in the container.

Comment: It can be because of the image mysql:5.7. I have try the same thing with mysql:8.0, it works.